Alignment out of spec after adjustment. Is it a concern?
Mechanic said this is the best he can do and there is no concern.
However, I see some values out of spec.
Is it concerning ?
This a toyota highlander AWD.


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

On most vehicles today, camber is not adjustable. You can sometimes get aftermarket kits which would let you to adjust it, but that isn't a regular thing. And for the most part, it isn't needed. The measurement on the front right seems to be just a bit off, so like your mechanic said, I don't think it's an issue. If the rubber mount at the top of the strut is worn out, this could be causing the issue and if changed might help. I'd assume the mechanic doing the alignment would have mentioned something like this if it were worn out. Another way this could be an issue is if the holes for the top mount were wallowed out, it would allow the strut at the top to move out of position. This could only happen if the fasteners at the top were loose. Again, this would have been brought up by the mechanic if it were an issue. The only other way it could be out is if there was some sort of suspension damage or frame damage (from an accident) which was not fixed properly.
As far as the toe on the back end, it is not adjustable, either. While the reading would be a concern for the front end, the back end isn't as big of a problem. Since the total toe is within spec, I don't think this will cause issues, either.

Thanks for the insight. For the front, he mentioned rusted knuckles. For the rear, he said it will require buying some hardware.

@HazemGomaa - Rusted knuckles shouldn't cause any issues with alignment. Considering the amount of cast iron which goes into them, we are talking centuries of rust before you'd have an issue with it.
